# Electron Error ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'electron' After update from 9 to 10

Tags: node.js, electron

Recently I update electron version from 9 to 10 and after updated getting this error on debug mode only
when I downgrade to 9 it's working correctly

Deleted Node_Module and package.lock file multiple times and reinstall all package but no luck

I tried to upgrade to 11 electrons also but facing the same issue

**When I am running in production mode "Yarn Start" is working fine
The issue in dev mode only "Yarn dev"**

ERROR:-

```
App threw an error during load Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'electron'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140:31)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542:40)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1165:22)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\SVN\mangocrossplatform\trunk\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:981:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:881:14)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:779:28)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023:19)
```

My Package.json File

```
{
  "name": "mangoapps-messenger",
  "productName": "Apps Messenger",
  "version": "15.0.11",
  "description": "Apps Messenger - An Universal Messenger For Apps",
  "homepage": "",
  "author": {
    "email": "",
    "name": ""
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn clean && concurrently \"yarn build-main\" \"yarn build-renderer\"",
    "build-dll": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --config ./configs/webpack.config.renderer.dev.dll.babel.js --colors",
    "build-main": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./configs/webpack.config.main.prod.babel.js --colors",
    "build-renderer": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./configs/webpack.config.renderer.prod.babel.js --colors",
    "dev": "yarn clean && cross-env START_HOT=1 node -r @babel/register ./internals/scripts/CheckPortInUse.js && cross-env START_HOT=1 yarn start-renderer-dev",
    "package": "yarn build && electron-builder build --publish never",
    "package-linux": "yarn build && electron-builder build --linux",
    "package-mac": "yarn build && CSC_LINK=./certs/mac.p12 && CSC_IDENTITY_AUTO_DISCOVER=false && electron-builder build --mac",
    "package-win": "yarn build && electron-builder build --win --x64",
    "package-win32": "yarn build && electron-builder build --win --ia32",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps && yarn build-dll && opencollective-postinstall",
    "preinstall": "node ./internals/scripts/CheckYarn.js",
    "prestart": "yarn build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production electron ./dist/main.prod.js",
    "start-main-dev": "cross-env HOT=1 NODE_ENV=development electron -r @babel/register ./app/main.dev.js",
    "start-renderer-dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config configs/webpack.config.renderer.dev.babel.js",
    "clean": "rimraf dist/"
  },
  "main": "./dist/main.prod.js",
  "build": {
    "productName": "Apps Messenger",
    "appId": "com.mangoapps.electrondesktop",
    "artifactName": "${name}-${version}.${ext}",
    "generateUpdatesFilesForAllChannels": true,
    "mac": {
      "category": "productivity",
      "type": "distribution",
      "provisioningProfile": "certs/mac.provisionprofile",
      "identity": "sdasdB",
      "hardenedRuntime": true,
      "entitlements": "build/entitlements.mac.inherit.plist",
      "entitlementsInherit": "build/entitlements.mac.inherit.plist",
      "gatekeeperAssess": false,
      "extendInfo": {
        "NSAppTransportSecurity": {
          "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads": true,
          "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription": "This lets you share using audio using the microphone.",
          "NSCameraUsageDescription": "This lets you share a photo or video taken from your camera.",
          "NSContactsUsageDescription": "This lets you enable access to your contacts and uses them to invite."
        }
      },
      "target": [
        "zip"
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "deb"
      ],
      "category": "Productivity"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis",
        "msi"
      ],
      "certificateFile": "",
      "certificatePassword": "",
      "publisherName": "",
      "requestedExecutionLevel": "asInvoker",
      "signAndEditExecutable": true,
      "signDlls": true
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": true,
      "perMachine": false,
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true
    },
    "msi": {
      "oneClick": true,
      "perMachine": true
    },
    "files": [
      "resources",
      "dist/",
      "dist/main.prod.js",
      "dist/main.prod.js.map",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "resources",
      "output": "release"
    }
  },
  "keywords": [
    "mangoapps",
    "messenger"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator": "^7.3.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.12.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.5.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-dev-expression": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "chalk": "^2.4.2",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "cross-spawn": "^6.0.5",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "detect-port": "^1.3.0",
    "electron": "^10.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^22.9.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.11.2",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
    "fbjs-scripts": "^1.2.0",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^24.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "opencollective-postinstall": "^2.0.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4",
    "react-svg-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "sinon": "^7.3.1",
    "spectron": "^5.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.3",
    "testcafe": "^1.1.0",
    "testcafe-browser-provider-electron": "^0.0.8",
    "testcafe-live": "^0.1.4",
    "testcafe-react-selectors": "^3.1.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1",
    "yarn": "^1.16.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.7.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.26",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.8",
    "@trodi/electron-splashscreen": "^0.3.4",
    "app-root-path": "^2.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "check-internet-connected": "^2.0.4",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.3.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "core-js": "2",
    "custom-electron-titlebar": "^3.2.2-hotfix62",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "electron-debug": "^2.1.0",
    "electron-dl": "^3.0.2",
    "electron-fetch": "^1.3.0",
    "electron-localshortcut": "^3.1.0",
    "electron-log": "^4.1.1",
    "electron-positioner": "^4.1.0",
    "electron-splashscreen": "^0.1.7",
    "electron-store": "^3.2.0",
    "electron-unhandled": "^3.0.2",
    "electron-util": "^0.14.1",
    "electron-window-state": "^5.0.3",
    "emoji-mart": "^2.11.1",
    "form-data": "^2.3.3",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "js-md5": "^0.7.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.27",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.27",
    "node-mac-notifier": "file:local_dep/node-mac-notifier",
    "node-machine-id": "^1.1.12",
    "node-notifier": "^8.0.0",
    "platform-folders": "^0.4.1",
    "plist": "^3.0.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.15",
    "react-image-crop": "^8.4.0",
    "react-lazyload": "^2.6.2",
    "react-page-layout": "^0.9.8",
    "react-phone-input-2": "^2.13.9",
    "react-player": "^1.15.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-select": "^3.0.3",
    "react-tenor": "^2.1.1",
    "react-toastify": "^6.0.8",
    "reactstrap": "^8.5.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.11",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.0",
    "universal-analytics": "^0.4.23",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.19",
    "zip-folder": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devEngines": {
    "node": ">=12.13.0",
    "npm": ">=6.12.0",
    "yarn": ">=1.19.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "defaults"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you resolve that?